# Why I can't access to a png image into a folder of my project?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a simple Java **Swing** application that show a login form (a JFrame) that have inside a JPanel with a background immage.

The problem is that if I put the location of the immagage using the **absolute path** of the immage I have no problem but if I try to use the **relative path** it go into error because seems that can't find the **.png** background immage.

This is my code:

```
package com.test.login;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import net.miginfocom.swt.MigLayout;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

public class LoginFrame2 extends SingleFrameApplication {

    private static final int FIXED_WIDTH = 550;
    private static final Dimension INITAL_SIZE = new Dimension(FIXED_WIDTH, 230);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> main()");
        launch(LoginFrame2.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside startup()");


        JFrame mainFrame = this.getMainFrame();         // main JFrame that represents the Windows
        mainFrame.setTitle("XCloud Login");

        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(INITAL_SIZE);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);

        Container mainContainer = mainFrame.getContentPane();       // main Container into the main JFrame


        // JPanel creation and settings of the MigLayout on it:
        // JPanel externalPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanelWithBackground externalPanel = null;

        try {
            externalPanel = new JPanelWithBackground("/resources/logo.png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        externalPanel.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout("fill"));

        externalPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"), "w 50%, wrap");

        JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField(20);

        externalPanel.add(userNameTextField, "w 90%, wrap");

        externalPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"), "w 50%, wrap");
        JTextField pswdTextField = new JTextField(20);
        externalPanel.add(pswdTextField, "w 90%, wrap");

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");

        externalPanel.add(loginButton, "w 25%, wrap");

        mainContainer.add(externalPanel);
        //mainFrame.add(mainContainer);

        show(mainFrame);


    }

}
```

The **logo.png** file is into the **resources** folder inside my project (at the same level of the src folder).

The line in which I try to access to this resource is:

```
externalPanel = new JPanelWithBackground("/resources/logo.png");
```

and the error is:

```
DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> main()
Inside startup()
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1275)
    at com.test.login.JPanelWithBackground.<init>(JPanelWithBackground.java:19)
    at com.test.login.LoginFrame2.startup(LoginFrame2.java:52)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:187)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
11-nov-2013 10.49.42 org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run
GRAVE: Application class com.test.login.LoginFrame2 failed to launch
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.login.LoginFrame2.startup(LoginFrame2.java:58)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:187)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class com.test.login.LoginFrame2 failed to launch
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:192)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.login.LoginFrame2.startup(LoginFrame2.java:58)
    at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:187)
    ... 14 more
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What's the JPanelWithBackground? Do you have SSCCE?

Comment: what is SSCCE...JPanelWithBackground is simply a class that extends a classic JPanel and that put the logo.png as background immage of this JPanel

Comment: How you create your image? show code?

Comment: Generally, when I have thos kind of error, I insert this simil- code in the catch clause: {File f = new File(Source_root); sysout (every file present in source_root with all attributes)} for seeing if there any error of permissions of user or directory path.

Comment: Or, instead of "/resources/logo.png", use File.Separator+ "resources"+ File.Separator+"logo.png"

Comment: You don't show the code that cause the exception: `JPanelWithBackground.java:19`. Please update your question with this important info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without forward slash. Works fine for me running from NetBeans and Eclipse

```
"resources/logo.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

**What's the output folder for your resources folder?**

I suppose it's the root of the built application ('bin'-directory, and later the root of the JAR), in that case the resource path would be:

```
"/logo.png"
```

Usually (depends on the IDE) you can have multiple source and resource folders, and define the output folders for each of them, as well as filters which content should be copied upon a build. Most generic example:

- **Source folder**: `/src`, Output folder: `/bin`, Filter: all but `.java` (Compiler will create and copy the class files instead)
- **Resource folder**: `/rsc`, Output folder: `/bin`, Filter: all files.
- **Assembly**: Content of `/bin` is packaged into a JAR

Example: resource `/rsc/images/icons/foo.png` will be copied to `/bin/images/icons/foo.png`, and it's path at runtime (given `'bin'` as root, or when packaged into a JAR) will be `/images/icons/foo.png`, that's then the path you use to load this resource at runtime.

Comment: don't work...same error...my project have the following structure: inside it there is a src directory (that contains my package) and the resources folder (that contains my logo.png immage)

Comment: And what is the output directory of the resources folder? Which IDE are your using? If it's Eclipse, check your configuration in the project's properties > Java Build Path > Source

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in next: 
You try to get image like next way `new ImageIcon("/resources/logo.png")` try to use next code:
`getClass().getResource("/resources/logo.png")` . I think it helps you.

EDIT: for creating `File` from it use

```
    URL resource = getClass().getResource("/resources/logo.png");
    File f = new File(resource.getFile());
```

Read more about [icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Answer (score 0):

The root of your project is probably even before your "src" directory. Try either setting the path to

> "/src/path/to/your/resources/logo.png"

or navigate relatively like this

> "../resources/logo.png"

Another way is to set the root directory to a variable.. This might come in handy for later use

```
private final String _RESOURCE_DIR = "/src/path/to/resources/";
File png = new File(_RESOURCE_DIR + "logo.png");
```